# Introducing ln variables causes VIF to increase above 10

Tags: stata, multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor

I am running a regression like this on Stata to do model diagnostics: xtreg lnTobinsQ l.ESGScore l.lnTotalAssets l.Leverage l.CurrentRatio l.PricetoBookValueperShare, fe

When I run the command vif, uncentered, I receive high VIF scores for lnTotalAssets (13.8) and ESGScore (9.14). Running a regression with TotalAssets and ESGScore without log-transformation does not cause high VIFs.

I also noticed that log-transformations of other large variables such as market cap, net income and total debt are highly correlated with ESGScores and running regressions with these variables produce high VIF scores for them and ESGScores. Am I running the model diagnostics correctly? What should I do in this situation? Thanks

Comment: When the relative range of your variables is small, the logarithm doesn't change much, producing high collinearity.  "What to do" depends on *why* you're taking logs in the first place. Please explain.